# Sequential Insertion of data using multiple procedure being called in sequence

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have a requirement where in I need to insert one row for customer and next for address and than all his account in a particular table.
For this I have written 3 procedure 1 calling 2 other in FOR LOOP.
While I am running it is running in sequence but when I check the data inserted. some of the rows of calling procedure are inserted before the called procedure are oveR. How to resolve the same?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE XYG(REP_DATE IN custom.C_CIBILRPT_TBL.RPT_DATE%type)
AS
  V_AS_COU    NUMBER DEFAULT 1;
  V_BS_COU    NUMBER DEFAULT 1;
  V_CS_TOT    NUMBER DEFAULT 1;
  V_BOD_DATE DATE;
  V_LINE_DATA VARCHAR(300);
BEGIN

  <<Getting Date into V_BOD_DATE using into statemet>>
  --#### Truncating Temp Table 
  execute immediate 'Truncate table CUSTOM.C_CIBILRPT_TMP';


  --#### Borrower Segment Generation Starts --####
  FOR custid IN
  ( Fetching customer id

  LOOP
    <<Getting the data in V_LINE_DATA>>
    INSERT
    INTO C_CIBILRPT_TMP VALUES
      (
        REP_DATE,
        V_BOD_DATE,
        'XXX',
        'BS',
        V_BS_COU,
        V_LINE_DATA,
        custid.cifid
      );
    COMMIT;
    V_BS_COU := V_BS_COU+1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (custid.cifid);


    ADDRESS_SEG_BG (custid.cifid,v_as_cou,rep_date);
    V_AS_COU := V_AS_COU+1;



    CREDIT_SEG_BG(custid.cifid,rep_date);


  END LOOP;

END XYG;
```

Comment: Can you post the actually output needed and whats happening currently. Your question is not pretty clear to me.

Comment: Hi, Yes Sure. I have multiple users and thr address and profile/account. Now I want First User Data Must be inserted that next row must be address data and finally all his account. than next customer data his address and all his accounts.